# How do I auto turn-off a DOS ONLY machine using software? The PC has NO POWER SWITCH

Tags: bios, shutdown, ms-dos

I have an old PC that has no power switch (it's a long story). It is running DOS 6.20.  I am looking for an interrupt call or anything to turn off the computer using software as I need it to turn off after unattended operations. I am a little familiar with ASM and interrupts and I'm not afraid to experiment.

Comment: I'm fairly sure there's no way to do this, but I'm not absolutely sure so I'm not listing this as an answer.

Comment: What about the `shutdown` command?

Comment: Search for a tool that powers off using APM (older) or ACPI (possibly too complex for DOS).

Comment: You can freely edit your own posts but for your protection, it must be done under the original user account.  It looks like you created a second account, which will also interfere with commenting on your thread and accepting an answer.  See http://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts to merge your accounts.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21463908/x86-instructions-to-power-off-computer-in-real-mode

Answer (score 3):

#### I am looking for an interrupt call or anything to turn off the computer

If you have ATX compatible hardware then you can use `ATXOFF.COM`

> ATXOFF.COM 1.3 english
>
> This simply turns off power on ATX Systems (no cache-flushing!), but
>   it requires APM 1.2 to work.

Source [dostools](http://home.germany.net/100-116853/dostools.htm)

> The ATXOFF.COM I have is only 40 bytes. Hardly worth griping over, or
>   continuing this childish gloating.
>
> Simply put. If the OP really wants a batch only solution, just
>   download a copy of ATXOFF, and create a DEBUG (native to 6.22) script
>   from it. Like this...
>
> ```
> === ATXOFF.SCR ===
> A
> MOV     AX,5301
> XOR     BX,BX
> INT     15
> MOV     AX,530E
> XOR     BX,BX
> MOV     CX,0102
> INT     15
> MOV     AX,5307
> XOR     BX,BX
> INC     BX
> MOV     CX,0003
> INT     15
> RET
>
> G
> ATXOFF.COM Version 1.3
> === End of ATXOFF.SCR ===
> ```
>
> Then all that needs done is to input the script into DEBUG in the
>   batch.
>
> ```
> debug < atxoff.scr > nul
> ```
>
> As mentioned elsewhere, this requires atx hardware, and when run, the
>   power goes off immediately, so be sure to flush your drive cache
>   first.

Source [shutdown and rebooting in batch files](http://www.verycomputer.com/12_44f2f5cba42a98db_1.htm)

Comment: How would one do the 'cache flushing' step then? I imagine it would involve smartdrv?

Comment: (Also, can someone tell me if `XOR BX,BX; INC BX` is equivalent to `MOV BX,0001`?)